# Combine recent and popular items in Views

Tags: 7, views

I need to show 2 popular and then 2 most recent items, and again next 2 popular and next 2 recent items in Views.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two separate views which will display two 2 popular items and  2 most recent items and use script below that will print content from these views on the page.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i = $i + 2) {
  $popular = views_get_view('popular');
  $popular->set_display('block');
  $popular->set_offset($i);
  $popular_content = $popular->preview();
  print $popular_content;

  $recent = views_get_view('recent');
  $recent->set_display('block');
  $recent->set_offset($i);
  $recent_content = $recent->preview();
  print $recent_content;
}
```